# Importing KMZ layer in to google maps - Vue 2

Tags: javascript, google-maps, vue.js

Using vue google maps package: https://github.com/xkjyeah/vue-google-maps

In a `mounted()` i am trying to set the layer:

```
mounted() {
  this.$refs.gmap.$mapPromise.then((map) => {
    let options = {
      url: 'https://beeline.kg/ru/binaries/content/assets/kmz-files/3g-v2.kmz'
    }
    let kml = new google.maps.KmlLayer(options)
    kml.setMap(this.$refs.gmap)
  })
},
```

However i'm getting in console: "InvalidValueError: setMap: not an instance of Map"

`this.$refs.gmap` is a reference to a google maps component:

```
<GmapMap
  ref="gmap"
  :center="{lat: lat, lng: lng}"
  :zoom="5"
  map-type-id="roadmap"
  style="width: 100%; height: 500px"
  :options="{
    mapTypeControl: false
  }"
>
</GmapMap>
```

THe problem is here i guess:

`let kml = new google.maps.KmlLayer(options)`

How to correctly call a new instance of google maps in case of using this package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It wasn't that hard actually. Just amazing, nobody has no clue on how to do it.

```
mounted() {
  this.$refs.gmap.$mapPromise.then((map) => {
    let options = {
      map: map,
      url: `https://example.com/filename.kmz?dummy=` + (new Date()).getTime()
    }
    let kml = new google.maps.KmlLayer(options)
  })
}
```

Dummy parameters is to avoid google maps caching.